# Spring Data - Order by like

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using Spring Boot and more and I want to sort my data using a like.
This native query runs very well:

```
select * from productos where nombrep like '%plastico%' order by nombrep like 'plastico%' desc;
```

[example how should show data in spring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14Br1.png)

```java
@Query(value = "select p from Producto p join fetch p.marca m join fetch p.categoria c join fetch p.proveedor pro join fetch p.presentacion pre where p.nombrep like %?1% order by p.nombrep like ?1% ", countQuery = "select count(p) from Producto p join p.marca m join p.categoria c join p.proveedor pro join p.presentacion pre where p.nombrep like %?1% order by p.nombrep like ?1%")
```

this does not work, and I can't found a lambda alternative using like.

Error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Already found parameter binding with same index / parameter name but differing binding type! Already have: LikeBinding [name: null, position: 1, type: CONTAINING
> (1): [IsContaining, Containing, Contains]], found LikeBinding [name: null, position: 1, type: STARTING_WITH (1): [IsStartingWith, StartingWith, StartsWith]]! If you bind a parameter multiple times make sure they use the same binding.

if I use two parameter (a copy of the first one)

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: like near line 1, column 201 [select p from com.grupoq.app.models.entity.Producto p join fetch p.marca m join fetch p.categoria c join fetch p.proveedor pro join fetch p.presentacion pre where p.nombrep like ?1 order by p.nombrep like ?2 ]

Comment: `this does not work` because of what? Exception? Incorrect ouput?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I edited my question. I tried two opcions

Comment: @ChrisGeek you forgot to encapsulate your `LIKE` argument into `'`. Proper syntax is `LIKE '%blabla%'`, not `LIKE %blabla%`

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I think that isn't necesary, The query (Spring data JPA) `where p.nombrep like %?1%`  works well without `'` , I did in that way but nothing change. I need to use **ORDER BY NOMBRE LIKE..** in spring data JPA